# dplyr using mutate + lag for the same column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use `dplyr` and it's `mutate` and `lag` functions to create a burndown based on another column and the previous value in the column I'm creating.

I have seen an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994136/r-is-it-possible-to-use-mutatelag-with-the-same-column)  that is asking for the same thing but the OP answered it themselves with using a loop. I am hoping there is a more eloquent solution to within `dplyr`.

sample (imagine df has 1000's rows):

```
      df <- data.frame(SCHED_SHIP_DATE = c("2019-09-10","2019-09-11","2019-09-12","2019-09-13"), quantity = c(156,52,136,285), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

      start <- 4000

      temp3 <- df %>%
        arrange(SCHED_SHIP_DATE) %>%
        mutate(burndown = ifelse(row_number() == 1, start, NA)) %>%
        mutate(burndown = lag(burndown, default = burndown[1]) - quantity)
```

I get the following output (`NA`'s after the it's done one row of mutate):

```
> temp3
  SCHED_SHIP_DATE quantity burndown
1      2019-09-10      156     3844
2      2019-09-11       52     3948
3      2019-09-12      136       NA
4      2019-09-13      285       NA
```

When I am expecting this:

```
> temp3
  SCHED_SHIP_DATE quantity burndown
1      2019-09-10      156     3844
2      2019-09-11       52     3948
3      2019-09-12      136     3812
4      2019-09-13      285     3527
```

Comment: Isn't replacing the last two lines with `mutate(burndown = start - quantity)` gives you the expected answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your desired output is a bit wrong. Here's what you probably need -

```
df %>%
  arrange(SCHED_SHIP_DATE) %>% 
  mutate(
    burndown = 4000 - cumsum(quantity)
    # burndown = pmax(4000 - cumsum(quantity), 0) # use this if you don't want -ve burndown
  )

  SCHED_SHIP_DATE quantity burndown
1      2019-09-10      156     3844
2      2019-09-11       52     3792
3      2019-09-12      136     3656
4      2019-09-13      285     3371
```

Comment: Thanks @Shree, you're right about my output above. I didn't even notice that it's not correct. Perfect answer!